# Find matching entries in list which are different

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, comparison, fuzzy-search

I have **two lists**. The first one contains entries like

- RB Leipzig vs SV Darmstadt 98
- Hertha Berlin vs Hoffenheim
- ..

and in the second contains basically the same entries but could but written in different forms. For example:

- Hertha BSC vs TSG Hoffenheim
- RB Leipzig vs Darmstadt 98
- ..

and so on. Both lists represent the same sport games but they can use **alternate team names** and **don't appear in the same order**.

**My goal** (hehe pun) is to unify both lists to one and match the same entries and discard entries which don't appear in both lists.

I already tried to use [Levensthein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and fuzzy search.
I thought about using machine learning but have no idea how to start with that.

Would appriciate any help and ideas!

Comment: Would be helpful to see the properties of both lists, sample data and the desired output

Comment: If you eliminated all of the all-caps substrings (e.g. TSG, SV, RB, and BSC) then how closely do the two lists' names match?

Comment: They could already be the same which would be very good or still differ alot for example `M'gladbach` and `Monchengladbach` are the same team but written differently.

Comment: Are the names used in each list consistent, e.g. if a list uses `M'gladbach` once then does it always use `M'gladbach`?

Comment: Yes, the names of one list are consistent.

Comment: Levensthein distance and other such algorithms are not the way to go about this. You'd be better off manually compiling a list of official team names and common alternates or misspellings. Then, when you go through your team lists you can normalize the names. After that, merging the lists is trivial. If you're talking about a few hundred unique teams, you can almost certainly normalize the names by hand a lot faster and more reliably than you can write a program to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem using [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) combined with the Levenshtein Distance you already mentioned. Linear Programming is a commonly used optimization technique for solving optimization problems, like this one. Check this link to find out an example how to use [Solver Foundation in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628587(v=vs.93).aspx). This example isn't related with the specific problem you have, but is a good example how the library works.

Hints:
You need to build a matrix of distances between each pair of teams/strings between 2 lists. Let's say both lists have N elements. In i-th row of the matrix you will have N values, the j-th value will indicate the Levenshtein Distance between i-th element from the first and j-th element from the second list. Then, you need to set the constraints. The constraints would be:

1. The sum in each row needs to equal 1
2. The sum in each column equals 1
3. Each of the coefficient (matrix entry) needs to be either 0 or 1

I have solved the same problem a couple of months ago and this approach worked perfectly for me.

And the cost function would be the sum: `

> sum(coef[i][j] * dist[i][j] for i in [1, n] and for j in [1, n])

`. You want to minimize this function, because you want the overall "distance" between the 2 sets after the mapping to be as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [BK-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) (I googled C# implementations and found two: [1](https://github.com/mkarlesky/csharp-bk-tree), [2](https://github.com/biggyspender/BkTree)).  Use the Levenshtein distance as the metric.  Optionally, delete the all-uppercase substrings from the names in the lists in order to improve the metric (just be careful that this doesn't accidentally leave you with empty strings for names).

```
1. Put the names from the first list in the BK-tree
2. Look up the names from the second list in the BK-tree
  a. Assign an integer token to the name pair, stored in a Map<Integer, Tuple<String, String>>
  b. Replace each team name with the token
3. Sort each token pair (so [8 vs 4] becomes [4 vs 8])
4. Sort each list by its first token in the token pair, 
   then by the second token in the token pair (so the list
   would look like [[1 vs 2], [1 vs 4], [2 vs 4]])
```

Now you just iterate through the two lists

```
int i1 = 0
int i2 = 0
while(i1 < list1.length && i2 < list2.length) {
  if(list1[i1].first == list2[i2].first && list1[i1].second == list2[i2].second) {
    // match
    i1++
    i2++
  } else if(list1[i1].first < list2[i2].first) {
    i1++
  } else if(list1[i1].first > list2[i2].first) {
    i2++
  } else if(list1[i1].second < list2[i2].second {
    i1++
  } else {
    i2++
  }
}
```